# "AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame' (most likely due to a circular import)" problem comes in vs code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have install pandas , but when i import pandas and  run any code in my vs code comes with this error

> "AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no
> attribute 'DataFrame' (most likely due to a circular import)".

help me to solve this.

I have tried many times with correct code and source. its should run the program correctly, but it shows error...

```
import pandas

mydataset = {
  'cars': ["BMW", "Volvo", "Ford"],
  'passings': [3, 7, 2]
}

myvar = pandas.DataFrame(mydataset)

print(myvar)
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem must be related to the installation of pandas or pip

make sure you have pandas installed by running:

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: comes with same error

Comment: Can you write 'pandas --version' in the console? Just to make sure you have the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I just got my **solution**:-
There is `two` major **reason** to come this **error**:

1. Don't download panda by **pip install panda** because there is diff. between **panda and pandas**,
   so download **pandas module/source** by **pip install pandas**.
2. Don't **Save** your file by name with **pandas.py**